# Exposing types through wrapper assembly

Tags: .net, dependencies

Suppose, I have three assemblies A1, A2, A3. A1 uses A2 and A2 uses A3. My problem is that A2 public function has a parameter which is an enumeration defined in A3, so to make use of A2 in A1 I also need to reference A3 just for this enumeration. I could of course create a new enumeration in A2 and then convert values, but it doesn't seem like a good solution. Is there any way that I can expose the enumeration in A3 through A2 to A1, so I don't have to reference A3 in A1 and A1 will only depend on A2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the enumeration is defined in A3 and A2 exposes a parameter / variable / property of that enumeration, you need to reference A3 in A1. There is no way around it.